# ¿Cómo cambiar el TabBarView actual?

Tags: flutter

Abusando de su amabilidad, quisiera pedirles ayuda con un problema que tengo al usar `TabBar`. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Verán, voy agregando un `Tab`, con su respectivo `TabBarView`, a mi `TabBar` cada que presiono un `FloatingActionButton` que tengo en pantalla. Estoy haciendo uso de un `TabController`.
Deseo que cada que agregue un nuevo `Tab` este tome el foco y su `TabBarView` se muestre en pantalla. Traté de hacerlo estableciendo en la propiedad `TabController.index` el indice de el último `Tab` creado y sí funcionó en parte.
Lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _tabController = new TabController(
        vsync: this,
        length: _productList.length,
    );
    _tabController.index = _productList.length-1;

    ...
    ...
}
```

**El problema es que**, aunque el último `Tab` sí toma el foco, el `TabBarView` que le corresponde no. Se mantiene el último que yo haya tenido en pantalla.
¿Cómo harían ustedes para que también el `TabBarView` cambie y tome el foco?

**Les dejo una captura de lo que les comento**, aquí pueden ver que el último Tab recibe el foco, pero el TabBarView que se muestra sigue siendo el de el 1er Tab, como se nota cuando arrastro hacia la derecha:
[image: El último Tab recibe el foco, pero el TabBarView sigue siendo el de el 1er Tab]

Gracias nuevamente. Estaré atento a sus comentarios para proporcionar la información que necesiten.

### **Actualización:**

Este es el código con el que cuento:
**Método build:**

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //* La definición del controlador se lleva a cabo aquí para poder
    //* reescribir la propiedad 'length' con cada setState, pues esta es final
    //* lo que impide modificar el valor que se le asigna al definirlo.
    _tabController = new TabController(
        vsync: this,
        length: _productList.length,
    );
    _tabController.index = _productList.length-1; //* El último Tab toma el foco
    _currentTab = _tabController.index; //* Índice del tab seleccionado.

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Agregar productos'),
            bottom: _createTabBar(),
        ),
        body: _createTabBarView(),
        floatingActionButton: _createFloatingActionButton(),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startDocked,
        persistentFooterButtons: _createPersistantFooterButtons(),
    );
}
```

Con este método se crea el TabBar:

```dart
TabBar _createTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: _productList.map((ProductModel product) {
            return Tab(text: 'Linea');
        }).toList(),
    );
}
```

Y con este se crea el TabBarView:

```dart
TabBarView _createTabBarView() {
    return TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: _productList.map((ProductModel product) {
            return ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 32.0),
                children: [
                    Column(
                        children: [
                            ...
                            ...
                            ...
                        ],
                    )
                ]
            );
        }).toList(),
    );
}
```

Gracias por su tiempo de verdad, espero que eso les sea util.

Comment: Serviría ver el código de implementación del TabBarView y la acción de tu botón flotante. Fuera de eso puede servirte este link: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs. ve el ejemplo del final.

Comment: @Uriel Manzano gracias por ti u tiempo. Ya agregué el código por si explica mejor las cosas, saludos!

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas lo puedes encontrar mejor explicado aquí: https://medium.com/@aurimas.deimantas/dynamic-tabbar-and-tabbarview-in-flutter-7f364b266aef

Comment: @Uriel Manzano muchas gracias por atender. Logré solventar el problema. Para que el TabBarView tomará el foco también, tenía que usar el método `animateTo` del TabController ‍♂️. Saludos y gracias por tu aporte!